# How can I remove index.php and add www in a CodeIgniter URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

My `.htaccess` file is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|img/|css/|js)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It removes `index.php` from the URL and forces a redirect from `example.net` to `www.example.net`, but when I enter `http://example.net`, it does not redirect to `www.example.net`. How can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In .htaccess file Change this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and in config file made 2 changes:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/CiFolderName';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

set your htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

remove index.php in your config

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Also allow overriding htaccess in your apache

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

and change

```
        AllowOverride All
```

and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

Have the.htaccess file in the application root directory, along with the index.php file. (Check if the htaccess extension is correct , Bz htaccess.txt did not work for me.)

And Add the following rules to .htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then find the following line in your application/config/config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Set the variable empty as below.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

That's it, it worked for me.

If it doesn't work further try to replace following variable with these parameters  ('AUTO', 'PATH_INFO', 'QUERY_STRING', 'REQUEST_URI', and 'ORIG_PATH_INFO') one by one

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```